# Visual Studio extension: splash info not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsx

I'm building (read: trying to build) a Visual Studio integration package, which contains some custom highlighting and intellisense. The language part is working fine, the package is being loaded in the IDE, installing on non-SDK machines without problems.

However, here's one annoying thing I can't get to work. I want to see my package details in the about box (which shows all the installed packages like Resharper), ditto for the splash screen.

According to the documentation, the method to do this is to implement the 'IVsInstalledProduct' interface. I did this, following the instructions on MSDN, but it simply doesn't work! When I put breakpoints on the methods it seems like they're never called. Hopefully there's anyone here who can enlighten me on why this doesn't work like it is supposed to.

Note:
I also ran devenv.exe /ranu /rootsuffix Exp /setup from the VS2008 command prompt, as recommended in other articles about this.

Comment: Is your package native or managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register your extension under the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\versionNumber\InstalledProducts` registry key?

If it's a managed package, don't forget to apply the `[InstalledProductRegistration]` attribute to it, which will handle the creation of that registry key.

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around with the project to get it to compile in a non-SDK environment (build server), so I forgot I commented out the link to the Microsoft.VsSDK.targets target, which handles the registering commands. I added it to the installed products manually, but incorrectly.